# Autohotkey RegExReplace Skip unmatched pattern

Tags: regex, autohotkey

How to skip an unmatched line in input on replacing by regex?

For Ex. Below is the contents of my test.txt

```
elkay_iyer@yahoo.com
elkay_qwer@yahoo.com
elke engineering ltd.,@yahoo.com
elke0265@yahoo.com
elke@yahoo.com
```

Below is my Autohotkey script with regex code

```
ReplaceEmailsRegEx := "i)([a-z0-9]+(\.*|\_*|\-*))+@([a-z][a-z0-9\-]+(\.|\-*\.))+[a-z]{2,6}"
RemoveDuplicateCharactersRegEx := "s)(.)(?=.*\1)"

Try{
FileRead, EmailFromTxtFile, test.txt
OtherThanEmails :=RegExReplace(EmailFromTxtFile,ReplaceEmailsRegEx)
Chars :=RegExReplace(OtherThanEmails,RemoveDuplicateCharactersRegEx)
Loop{
StringReplace, OtherThanEmails, OtherThanEmails, `r`n`r`n,`r`n, UseErrorLevel
If ErrorLevel = 0
Break
}
If (StrLen(OtherThanEmails)){
Msgbox The Characters found other than email:`n%OtherThanEmails%
}
}
catch e {
ErrorString:="what: " . e.what . "file: " . e.file . " line: " . e.line . " msg: " . e.message . " extra: " . e.extra
Msgbox An Exception was thrown`n%ErrorString%
}
Return
```

When it replace on `test.txt` it throws error:

```
e.what contains 'RegExReplace', e.line is 10
```

It executes without error when I remove 3rd email in `test.txt`. So how to change my regex to skip the problematic string?

Comment: It exits from the execution of the whole file on error. So it skips remaining valid email matches

Comment: For the person who downvoted: May I know the reason so that I can improve my next posts to be useful.

Comment: You got a classical catastrophic backtracking with your regex. Where did you get this pattern from? Please try `i)[a-z0-9]+(?:(?:\.+|_+|-+)[a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z][-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}`. Or `i)[a-z0-9]+(?:([._-])\1*[a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z][-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it worked. Your's is the answer. The catastrophic backtracked regex was created by me. That's why it worked like a charm. lol

Comment: I think the downvote is due to the question itself - matching emails is so common a task that you can easily find a better regex for this by just searching SO via Google (I find Google search better than SO built-in one).

Comment: I thought 'Skipping unmatched pattern' stuff would make this post unique. Anyhow, I am fine. I will let it be.

Comment: It looks unique in the number and quality of issues with the regex :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is *catastrophic backtracking* due to the nested quantifier in the beginning: `([a-z0-9]+(\.*|\_*|\-*))+`. Here, the `.`, `_` and `-` are all optional due to the `*` quantifier and thus your pattern gets reduced to `([a-z0-9]+)+`.

I suggest "unrolling" the first subpattern to make it linear:

```
i)[a-z0-9]+(?:(?:\.+|_+|-+)[a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z][-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}
```

Or

```
i)[a-z0-9]+(?:([._-])\1*[a-z0-9]+)*@(?:[a-z][-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}
```

You may even remove `\1*` if you do not allow more than 1 `.` or `_` or `-` in between "words".

Also, there is no need in using `\-*` with alternation in `(\.|\-*\.)`, as the hyphen is matched with the previous character class, thus, this subpattern can be reduced to `\.`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gE6cW2/2)